# Introduce a "Suggest edit" while inserting a comment

Tags: feature-request

It seems that most of the new users are afraid when, after posting their very first question, someone welcomes him, saying:

"Hi man... **please add more details and the efforts you did to solve your problem**..."

Indeed, I think that new users aren't aware of the "Edit" button that they can use to edit the question.

I have a proposal...

> Inserting the option "Suggest edit" when adding a comment to an answer

When a user receive a "Suggest edit", there is something that catch his attention, so there will be no reason not to see the "Edit" button.

Of course, this must be adjusted in someway. For example, not all users may have the right to send a "Suggest edit", this privilege must be conquered.

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's up to commenters to make it clear what they suggest the user to do. All they need to do is to type

> Please [edit] your question to ...

and the site automatically makes the word "edit" a link, so that even if the user didn't notice grey "edit" under the post, they can click that link and get to the same place (the post editor).

Comment: wow, sweet. I did not know this was a thing.